# Selecting a link based on href and link text and then updating text

Tags: jquery

How would one select a link in a div based on the href value and the text content and then update the text?

I have tried the below unsuccessfully:

```
$(".myclass a[href*='XYZ'],:contains('PQR')").text('Change text');
```

Comment: `$(".myclass a[href*='XYZ']:contains('PQR')")` remove comma

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `,` and it should work just find

```js
$(".myclass a[href*='XYZ']:contains('PQR')").text('Change text');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  <a href="XYZ" class="">PQR</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are my questions always downvoted here? They are perfectly reasonable questions, no?

Comment: @podusmonens I think the reason why your question was downvoted by someone is because the only error was the `,` something that maybe could have been a simple type error.